# Activity id in ASP.NET Core 2 application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a new application in ASP.NET Core 2 with MVC.

[image]

Then, as I opened the Error Action Method in HomeController

```cs
public IActionResult Error()
{
    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

I am not able to understand both Activities as well as HttpContext.TraceIdentifier.

What's itching me more is the question mark(?) after Activity.Current(**Activity.Current?.Id**). Some new syntax?

Answer (score 3):

The `?` is a [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators). It's a new feature in c# 6 that makes null checking easier.

`Activity.Current?.Id` and `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` in this context are unique tracking ids so you can correlate the request with logs and telemetry.

Generally, `Activity.Current` will be null if you're not using [application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) or [managing activities yourself](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/ActivityUserGuide.md), hence the `?` being present.